# Why we dont need to use "require" statement but still be able to use the build-in function?

Tags: lua

In C language, we use `#include` statement and `using` statement in C# to be able to attach its build-in function. But in Lua, we dont need to do anything, then we can use the `coroutine`, `table`, `io`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. C and C# aren't Lua; different languages behave differently.

Comment: BTW—`require` is a function and, ironically, it's a built-in function.

Comment: Lua has very small amount of standard libraries, so all the libraries are loaded into RAM when Lua VM starts.  Other languages are unable to do the same :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because Lua "pre-imports" some of the libraries for you. You can re-configure your copy of Lua to load a different set of libraries. See `lualib.h` file in the Lua distribution for the list of pre-loaded libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The Lua interpreter exports all basic functions and library tables to Lua programs by calling [luaL_openlibs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_openlibs) before running the program.

EDIT:

**Why don't all languages do this?**

It's a trade-off. If a language exposes its entire standard library by default, it saves us a lot of boilerplate. On the other hand, it can pollute the namespace, use more memory, and increase startup time. Lua's standard library is small, so it doesn't cost very much. Most compiled languages try to be as lean as possible, so they make us import everything explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sincerely. This question came to mind when I use ToLua in Unity to build my game. And I find that many of its scripts don't have a "require" statement, but some global variables and functions can still be used in other scripts. I just can't figure out why the author of ToLua can do that.

Comment: Is there any way I use "require" statements in one scripts, requiring all the other scripts, and all the global functions and variables can be used by any other script.

Comment: If you're talking about user-defined stuff, anything that you don't declare `local` is global (except parameters and looping variables).